# Why can't runtime APIs have default implementations?

Tags: runtime, runtime-api

I encountered a compile error `error: A runtime API function cannot have a default implementation!` when attempting to define a default implementation for a runtime API.

Why is this not possible?

Comment: Where did you come across this error?

Comment: While writing a new runtime API.